# Meaning of "brave the heat "?

Tags: american-english, spoken-english

What Is its meaning?  I already looked it up on the internet but couldn't find anything. Also please tell me some good examples.  Thanks

Comment: In general, it's a good idea to provide a complete sentence or paragraph if possible. Also, you looked it up, but _what_ did you find? It's helpful if you provide that here.

Comment: We English speakers tend to exaggerate. We brave the heat, we brave the rain, we brave the crowds at big sales, we brave the long line at the DMV, we brave the waves at the beach, we brave the highway traffic.

Answer (score 1):

To brave something means: "to face or endure it".

Brave verb
[WITH OBJECT]
Endure or face (unpleasant conditions or behaviour) without showing fear.
‘these six men braved the rough seas’ - [English Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/brave)